# pass the multiple value in post api?

Tags: reactjs, api, message-passing

Here is my post api request, I need this data from front-end:

[image]

Consider the code below, the `users_id` is actually getting from localStorage, while `items_id` taken from another api that I have been call from `componentDidMount`:

```
purchaseOrder(){
        const Users_id = localStorage.getItem('id'); // get user_id
        const items_id = this.state.data.id; // get items_id
        console.log(Users_id)
        console.log(items_id)
        PostData('api/purchase-order-item/submit', this.state).then ((result) => {  // how to pass the users id and items id to api?
            let responseJSON = result;
            console.log(responseJSON);
            console.log(this.state)
            });
    }
```

this.state :

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

   this.state ={
      data: [],
      remark: '', //for api 
      quantity: '', // for api
      isLoaded: false,
      redirect: false,
      history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
   }
    this.purchaseOrder = this.purchaseOrder.bind(this);
     this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the `remark` and `quantity` from the state and then pass a new plain object as the API post data:

```
const users_id = localStorage.getItem('id'); // get user_id
const items_id = this.state.data.id; // get items_id
const { remark, quantity } = this.state;
PostData('api/purchase-order-item/submit', { remark, quantity, users_id, items_id }).then ((result) => {
```

Comment: Cool!!!  Thanks for your guidance